# KDF3 - implementation explanation

Tags: key-derivation, reference-request

An old project that I did not code is using the KDF3 algorithm, but I struggle to find an explanation about the way this key derivation algorithm works.
I know that this algorithm is part of the ISO-18033-2:2006, but it is pretty expensive.

Can someone explain it to me ?

Comment: Some suggestions: 1) if you have to maintain compatibility, ask your employer to buy the standard from your national standardization organ, or you can try local libraries where there often is a section for inter/intra-national standards and academic journals. 2) Consider functionally replace the component with better alternatives such as ECIES (available for free from http://secg.org) or Curve-25519/448 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7748).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I do not plan to modify the current implementation. the algorithm is implemented on an embedded system with not much horsepower, so I don't think that asymmetric/ECC cryptography would be a good idea.

Comment: There seems to be a well written version in BASIC (of all things) [here](https://forum.powerbasic.com/forum/user-to-user-discussions/source-code/60253-key-derivation-functions-kdf1-kdf2-kdf3-iso-18033-2). And [here](https://github.com/peio/KDF/blob/master/KDF.py) it is in Python. Looks similar, but pay attention to the `pAmt` and it's size; I'm not 100% if that's correct in the Python code.